# The 3rd data cell won't align all the way to the right

Tags: html, css

I created a wrapper with three data cells to fill 100% of the area. The 3rd data cell should be aligned all the way to the right, but as you can see in my jsfiddle, it isn't aligned all the way to the right. I have the outer cells at 48% and the middle cell at 4% so it adds up to 100%. What do I need to change?

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/5cypdu4q/2/

My HTML

```
<div class="wrapper-data">
    <div class="data_cell1">
        <p><strong>Contact</strong>: Link Polk, Manager<br />
        <strong>Phone</strong>: (407) 665-7177<br />
        <strong>Email</strong>: <a href="mailto:LPolk@seminolecountyfl.gov">LPolk@seminolecountyfl.gov</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="data_cell2"></div>
    <div class="data_cell3">
        <p class="right"><strong>Fax</strong>: (407) 665-7183<br />
        <strong>Department</strong>: Budget<br />
        <strong>Agency</strong>: Seminole County, Florida</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
/* Wrapper - Data */

    .wrapper-data {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
        overflow: hidden;
            border:1px solid black;
    }

        .wrapper-data p {
            font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
            font-size:16px;
            color:#616161;
            margin:0 0 0 49px;
            text-align:left;
            font-weight:normal;
            line-height: 24px;
    }

        .wrapper-data p.right {
            font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
            font-size:16px;
            color:#616161;
            margin:0 0 0 80px;
            text-align:left;
            font-weight:normal;
            line-height: 24px;
    }

    .data_row {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .data_cell1 {
        width: 48%;
        white-space: normal;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .data_cell2 {
        width: 4%;
        display: table-cell;
        white-space: normal;
    }

    .data_cell3 {
        width: 48%;
        display: table-cell;
        white-space: normal;
            border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to align the text of 3rd data cell to right?

Comment: I don't want the text aligned to the right. I just don't know why the end of the 3rd cell border isn't all the way to the right. It stops short about 100 to 150 pixels. There is spacing to the right of the border of the 3rd cell

Comment: Not sure I follow what your asking. The third column is flush against the right side of the body for me.

Comment: You must be on a smaller screen. Check out the screenshot I posted. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_QZSeh-fxH0SHNaSGZtaUZMZTQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

float property may do the trick, but 2nd  column should have data at least and the 3rd should be 47% for the sake of border you defined

```
.data_cell1 {
    width: 48%;
    white-space: normal;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}

.data_cell2 {
    width: 4%;
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: normal;
    float: left;
}

.data_cell3 {
    width: 47%;
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: normal;
        border:1px solid red;
        float: right;
}
```

or for 3rd column use

```
.data_cell3 {
    width: 48%;
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: normal;
    outline:1px solid red;
    float: right;
}
```

3rd column leave the width as desired but change border to outline, outilne has no effect to the container width where border, padding or margin does

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put in the .data_row div class in my code.

That fixed it.